# Cytoscape Concentric layout start and end angles

Tags: javascript, html, layout, cytoscape.js

In Cytoscape, i want to build a graph with the concentric layout, but not a full circle, more like a half or quarter circle with one element in the center of the graph and all other elements on the outer side.

Is there a way to alternate the existing concentric layout from http://js.cytoscape.org?
The problem is, that I can't use endAngle apparently, and I couldn't find anything about that online yet. I search for something like this:

```
layout = cy.elements().layout({

    name: 'concentric',
    fit: true,
    padding: 30, 
    startAngle: 3/2 * Math.PI, // where nodes start in radians
    endAngle: 5/2 * Math.PI,// this doesn't work
    sweep: undefined,     
    clockwise: true, 
    equidistant: false, 
    minNodeSpacing: 10, 
    boundingBox: undefined, 
    avoidOverlap: true, 
    nodeDimensionsIncludeLabels: false, 
    height: undefined, 
    width: undefined, 
    spacingFactor: undefined, 
    concentric: function (node) { return node.degree();},
    levelWidth: function (nodes) { return nodes.maxDegree() / 4;},
    animate: false, 
    animationDuration: 500, 
    animationEasing: undefined, 
    animateFilter: function (node, i) { return true; }, 
    ready: undefined, 
    stop: undefined, 
    transform: function (node, position) { return position; } 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `endAngle` mentioned in the docs.  Read the docs carefully and use only supported fields.

From the docs:

```
startAngle: 3 / 2 * Math.PI, // where nodes start in radians
sweep: undefined, // how many radians should be between the first and last node (defaults to full circle)
```

So you can specify a start and a delta rather than a start and an end, like you tried.

E.g. `cy.layout({ name: 'concentric', startAngle: 0, sweep: Math.PI/2 }).run();`

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that should do it!